# Signing into Firebase with email only (no links, no password)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Preface: **Nothing secure is being stored with this -- it's a test project of mine to see what's possible and what's not.**

I've been scanning the docs for a way to sign a user in (on a website) with *just* their email, without them needing to go to their inbox for an auth link or enter a password.

Is this technically possible with Firebase Auth?

A potentially hacky way I was thinking of was having a hidden password field, in which every user has the same password and it's prefilled via Javascript.

Comment: What does "signing in with just an email" mean in that scenario? How would you prevent somebody else from "signing in" with that exact same email? I have a feeling this is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what is the use-case you're trying to implement?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it is possible as you describe it. If you are fine with it you can use for all users the same password and let all of them just enter the email on registration and login. You don't even need to hide it in some fields. Just put it in the code as clear text:

-registration

```js
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, "yourPassword")
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

-login

```js
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, "yourPassword")
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

By using [fetchSignInMethodsForEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#fetchsigninmethodsforemail) you could detect if a user is registered or not and do this automaticaly in the background so your users only need to enter the email no matter if they have bin on your side or not. The UX would be the same for new and old users.

**WARNING**: This is technically possible to do like this. I and everyone else recommend you not to do this. Someone could use that same password to get user data from ppl just by knowing they'r email or do other harmfull stuff to your project.

Maybe you could explain to us why you want to do that and maybe we can find a bette solution for you.

Comment: Thank you, Tarik - I totally agree with you on all points. Good call on using the fetchSignInMethodsForEmail to check for registration.

Comment: I'm still curious why you need it like that :) It would be great if you could mark the answer as accepted.